# Order by descending the upadated_at column in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

```
$notif = DB::table('notifications')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Above code is to get the values in descending order according to the default column updated_at in laravel 5. Although that will display the values ascending order. I want to display the most recently updated one at first.How to correct that?

[image: Last column of this picture indicates the updated_at column. There I need to get the row which has the recent updated time first. How to solve that?]

Comment: How are you checking that the result is in the wrong order? I suggest you using the fantastic `tinker` tool.

Comment: By viewing the database table

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are viewing the results from phpmyadmin or something similar. The code

```
$notif = DB::table('notifications')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

will give you results in your web application.
It'll not store the records in descending order in the database as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `$notif = DB::table('notifications')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();` definately gives you the right sorting. As @linuxartisan already mentioned: are you sure your tool you are using for showing the database uses the right sort direction? It seems `11, 12` in your first column is the the `id` and the sort order is using `id ascending`